# How to create a postgres user with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to allow the creation of database users/roles through a web application that uses Python and SQLAlchemy in the backend.

To do that i'm using something like:

```py
sql = 'CREATE USER :username WITH PASSWORD :passwd'
sql_data = {
    "username": "the_user_name",
    "passwd": "the_password",
}
request.db.execute(sql, sql_data)
```

But the SQL created by this query is:

```sql
CREATE USER 'the_user_name' WITH PASSWORD 'the_password'
```

and what I need is:

```sql
CREATE USER "the_user_name" WITH PASSWORD 'the_password'
```

with the username properly escaped. Is there a way that SQLAlchemy can handle this or should I create the string manually? If so, how can I escape the user input name?

Comment: Not exactly i probe different strategies nowaday for things like this. One easy way is something like: `sql = f"CREATE USER quote_ident('{username}') WITH PASSWORD :passwd'` it is sql injection safe an easy readable combining f-strings with parametrized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [quoted_name](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.quoted_name):

> Represent a SQL identifier combined with quoting preferences.
>
> quoted_name is a Python unicode/str subclass which represents a
> particular identifier name along with a quote flag. **This quote flag,
> when set to True or False, overrides automatic quoting behavior for
> this identifier in order to either unconditionally quote or to not
> quote the name**. If left at its default of None, quoting behavior is
> applied to the identifier on a per-backend basis based on an
> examination of the token itself.

Here is how I was able to get it to work:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text, quoted_name

DATABASE_USER = "your_user_here"
DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD = "your_password"

create_user_sql = text(f"CREATE USER {quoted_name(DATABASE_USER, False)} WITH PASSWORD :database_password")\
    .bindparams(                                     # You can remove this line if you don't want to test
        database_password=DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD.    # You can remove this line if you don't want to test
    )\                                               # You can remove this line if you don't want to test
    .compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}) # You can remove this line if you don't want to test
print(str(create_user_sql))                          # You can remove this line if you don't want to test
```

Results in the following being executed:

```
CREATE USER your_user_here WITH PASSWORD 'your_password'
```

**You can remove the `.bindparams()` and `.compile()` and just pass the parameter(s) to `connection.execute(create_user_sql, database_password=DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD)` which looks cleaner, the code above is just a proof of concept.**

Comment: This means that `quoted_name` is called without knowledge of the specific dialect in use. That's... not optimal.