# Avoid SQL injection when creating user with SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg3

When creating a user with `psycopg`, I would create the following composite in order to avoid SQL injection:

```
from psycopg.sql import SQL, Identifier, Literal

username = "test_user"
password = "test_password"
query = SQL(
    "CREATE USER {username} WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD {password};"
).format(username=Identifier(username), password=Literal(password))
```

This can be tested in the scope of a `psycopg.Connection`:

```
print(query.as_string(connection))  # CREATE USER "test_user" WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'test_password';
```

What is the recommended way to do the same with `sqlalchemy`? I tried `quoted_name` and `bind_params`, but the former was not successful:

```
from sqlalchemy import quoted_name, text

query = text(
    f"CREATE USER {quoted_name(username, True)} WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD :password;"
).bindparams(password=password).compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})

print(query)  # CREATE USER test_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'test_password';
```

(Changing the second parameter of `quoted_name` to `False` or `None` yields the same result.)

Comment: I see we have [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925260/how-to-create-a-postgres-user-with-sqlalchemy) that advises the approach you're using here. That's unfortunate. A proper answer will probably use `sqlalchemy.schema.DDL` with `%s` placeholders for context -- which we want evaluated only _at compile time_, not when the query string is built, so the engine's dialect details are available.

Comment: I would construct the statement with as in the first example, wrap it with `sqlalchemy.text` and execute it. Database admin actions aren't really the use-case for SQLAlchemy (or most other ORMs).

Comment: @snakecharmerb The expression `text(SQL(...))` leads to a `TypeError` since `text` expects a string or bytes-like object. In addition, if I have to use `psycopg` constructs, I can just do everything in `psycopg` instead of mixing the two libraries. Nonetheless, I have hope that SQLAlchemy Core supports what I am asking for (SQLAlchemy ORM not, of course).

Comment: I should been more explicit: you would need to call the SQL object's `as_string()` method to stringify it prior before passing it to `text()`.

Comment: Alas, I've hit my timebox trying to run this down. Back when I used SQLAlchemy on a regular basis (in the 1.x days), @zzzeek was actively available on support channels (largely IRC, at the time). I'd generally suggest trying to go direct to the source on this one, accordingly.